# How to make better RESTful links SEO on static content website with Apache and PHP Router

Tags: seo, php, apache, 301-redirect

I have a pretty old website (running on Apache) that serves around 50 static HTML pages.
And so I want to change it and add PHP Router to help me serve content in a RESTful way.

Now I have tried several things, but I don't know **how good** they are.

Say I have old page  `example.com/fooBar.html`
I want to be able to serve it from  `example.com/foo/bar` and:

- keep old website link versions accessible from outside: `example.com/fooBar.html`
- make all requests go through `index.php` where I can use PHP Router, serve proper content for requests, keep old meta tags content intact (RESTful URIs should have same exact data)
- NOT have ugly links like this: `example.com/index.php?page=foo/bar`
- keep old version of a website's Google rating somewhat same
- keep 301 Redirects to a minimum (2 is max I guess?)
- change all website's inner links to new RESTful versions

So far I see that I can reference old pages to index like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

This sends old pages to `index.php` and I can route Old Resources to New Ones like so:
Changing location with router: `$response->header("Location", "/foo/bar");`

So the goal is for the location to look like `example.com/foo/bar`:

```
"example.com/fooBar.html" => index.php Router => "example.com/foo/bar"
"example.com/foo/bar"     => index.php Router => "example.com/foo/bar"
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea.  The only thing that I would suggest would be to change your rewrite condition somewhat.  I would use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  # not a real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  # not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l  # not a symbolic link
```

This would prevent the rewrite rule from triggering on *index.php* (just like your rule does.)  It would also allow you to serve other files (such as a *robots.txt* file, image files, or a pdf file) in the normal static manner.